# Fetching videos in my channel using the YouTube v2 API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am unable to get the videos through my API using username:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=""&v=2&alt=jsonc
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? What should I try or look for when debugging?

Comment: "innernet Ab" is your channel title. Since you could not choose one, it's your channel ID without the UC prefix. Note that API V2 is deprecated. Anyway, maybe this url: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/hgFhtIUYqH_kOcGSGW6pFQ/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

Answer (score 1):

Using v2 of the API, the proper URL would be:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[USER_NAME]/uploads

No oAuth is needed if you're just doing a read-only call.

Comment: ok but I am getting an error unable to find my username my username is innernet Ab can you please help me in solving this.

Comment: Go to http://www.youtube.com/account <- you will find your username there. If it doesnt work click on "advanced" and use your user ID.